# help - change diff symbol "<", "|" or ">" to a desired one?

Tags: linux, vim, diff

diff -w command is used to create a side by side comparison diff file (instead of parallel)
i then view them using vi via ssh terminal 
the changes are indicated by either "<" or "|" or ">"
Since the file i am viewing is a source code, navigating to changes alone
using above symbols is difficult since they are also in C source code.

How can i change these default symbols to desired ones ?
Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't off-topic.  It's a question for programmers about programming tools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of viewing the output of `diff -w` in vim, you can use vim's built-in diff:

```
vim -d file1 file2
```

This opens vim in a vertical split with both files open, and diff markings in the code.  This is what it looks like:

[image]

And it works in a terminal too:

[image]

You can find a short tutorial [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/vimdiff-edit-two-or-three-versions-of-a-file-with-vim-and-show-differences.html)

Answer (score 2):

According to my version of diff (2.8.1 from the GNU diffutils by the FSF) -w is used to change the width of the output; The -y parameter outputs side by side comparison. In combination, the two show no further effect than the -y parameter used alone, which means you may have an alias in your terminal profile or in the global terminal profile that aliases diff to diff -y.

I say all this because all options to change the symbols ("<", "|", and ">") conflict with the -y option. If you can live without side-by-side, you have the option of two other included output styles or defining your own. The two output styles are -c (context) and -u (unified). (For more information on what they do see the [diff Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff). For more information on the options see the [diff man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff).)

A more in depth fix would be to use the following options:

```
diff --old-group-format="(deleted)---" \
     --new-group-format="(added)---" \
     --changed-group-format="(updated)---" \
     --unchanged-group-format="(nodiff)---" \
     old_file.c new_file.c
```

Now the old file's lines that are not present in the new file are represented by **(deleted)---**

The new file's lines that are not present in the old file are represented by **(added)---**

Lines that have been changed are represented by **(updated)---**

Lines common to both files are represented by **(nodiff)---**

Since you seem to do this often enough, you have the option of making it an alias in your terminal profile or writing a small shell script to handle it. For more options, see the manual's [section on options](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/#diff-Options) and specifically see the [section on line group formats](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/#Line-Group-Formats) for information on what you can put between the quotes in the format definitions.

Of course, if you must have side-by-side, try Nathan Fellman's idea above. Otherwise, there's the option of using a dedicated GUI tool for it such as Kompare.